# Beaglebone green usb ssh issues

Tags: beagleboneblack

Unable to ssh BBG through usb. I am using putty for ssh. It throws error like 'Network error: Connection timed out'.
USB drivers (BONE_D64.exe) gets installed properly.
When BBG connected through PC USB port, Mass Storage drive 'BeagleBone Getting Started' opens up fine, under Device Manager RNDIS and CDC port shows up fine.

One weird thing I observed is, Local Area Connection for BBG shows IP address as 169.254.133.251 which means error. It should be 192.168.7.1.

What might be the problem? I tried reinstalling drivers but no good results.
My host machine is running windows 7 (64 bit) and BBG running Debian Jessie 8.7 IoT.

Comment: Try to manually change your's machine IP address to 192.168.7.1 and then ping the BBG like "ping 192.168.7.2"

Comment: @electrospark Make sure you're trying to ssh to the correct ip address. Best way of knowing the IP address is by logging in your router and going under "Connected Devices" and finding the ip address, then you can do "ssh root@192.168.7.2" assuming 192.168.7.2 is the IP address showing under the BBB device on your router's homepage. Then it should ask you to enter your password for root.